# Get inertia for nltk k means clustering using cosine_similarity

Tags: python, nltk, k-means

I have used nltk for k mean clustering as I would like to change the distance metric. Does nltk k means have an inertia similar to that of sklearn? Can't seem to find in their documentation or online...

The code below is how people usually find inertia using sklearn k means.

```
inertia = []
for n_clusters in range(2, 26, 1):
  clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
  preds = clusterer.fit_predict(features)
  centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_
  inertia.append(clusterer.inertia_)

plt.plot([i for i in range(2,26,1)], inertia, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Sum_of_squared_distances')
plt.title('Elbow Method For Optimal k')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write your own function to obtain  the inertia for  Kmeanscluster  in nltk.

As per your  question posted by you,  [How do I obtain individual centroids of K mean cluster using nltk (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538701/how-do-i-obtain-individual-centroids-of-k-mean-cluster-using-nltk-python/59541934#59541934) . Using the same dummy data, which look like this. after making 2 cluster..
[image]

Refereing to docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html, inertia is  Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center.

```
 feature_matrix = df[['feature1','feature2','feature3']].to_numpy()
 centroid = df['centroid'].to_numpy()

 def nltk_inertia(feature_matrix, centroid):
     sum_ = []
     for i in range(feature_matrix.shape[0]):
         sum_.append(np.sum((feature_matrix[i] - centroid[i])**2))  #here implementing inertia as given in the docs of scikit i.e sum of squared distance..

     return sum(sum_)

 nltk_inertia(feature_matrix, centroid)
 #op 27.495250000000002

 #now using kmeans clustering for feature1, feature2, and feature 3 with same number of cluster 2

scikit_kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters= 2)
scikit_kmeans.fit(vectors)  # vectors = [np.array(f) for f in df.values]  which contain feature1, feature2, feature3
scikit_kmeans.inertia_
#op
27.495250000000006
```

Comment: hi @qaiser, do you know how can I change the distance metric of the k mean to canberra distance for example? thank you!

Comment: @atjw94 u can raise a new question for this with little more explanation ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554641/changing-k-mean-clustering-distance-metric-to-canberra-distance-or-any-other-dis here you go, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The previous comment is actually missing a small detail:

```
feature_matrix = df[['feature1','feature2','feature3']].to_numpy()
centroid = df['centroid'].to_numpy()
cluster = df['predicted_cluster'].to_numpy()

 def nltk_inertia(feature_matrix, centroid):
     sum_ = []
     for i in range(feature_matrix.shape[0]):
         sum_.append(np.sum((feature_matrix[i] - centroid[cluster[i]])**2))  

     return sum(sum_)
```

You have to select the corresponding cluster centroid when calculating distance between centroids and data points. Notice the **cluster** variable in the above code.