# Changing K mean clustering distance metric to canberra distance or any other distance metric on python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, k-means

How do I change the distance metric of k mean clustering to canberra distance or any other distance metric? From my understanding, sklearn only supports euclidean distance and nltk doesn't seem to support canberra distance but I may be wrong. Thank you!

Comment: just look at this  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric

Answer (score 1):

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from nltk.cluster.kmeans import KMeansClusterer

obj = KMeansCluster(num_cluster, distance = distance.canberra)
```

Comment: May (A) fail to converge - k-means *only* minimizes sum-of-squares, not distances, and (B) performance will be quite slow.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse -Reinstate Monica how should I approach it then? Currently the code is still running for a very long time...

Comment: @qaiser its a project to try out various distance metric, moreover dataset has many features, 30 to 60 features

Comment: you can refer to this paper if you are interested, of course I'm not the author, but doing something similar https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0144059&type=printable

Comment: @atjw94 it is an ill-posed project if your task is to try out different distance metrics with k-means, because k-means does not work this way. You can use hierarchical clustering, here arbitrary distances can be used reliably (at least with many linkages, not with Ward).

Comment: That PLOS paper cannot be recommended. It is of rather poor quality. Some complexities given are wrong - don't show that to someone from complexity theory. They clearly have a number of numerical issues with distances that *should* always yield identical results but don't; and of course they shouldn't be using some of the measures with k-means, so no wonder that often k-medoids worked better...

Comment: in the paper also, for canberra  distance in uses and advantage kmedoids and hierarchical clustering  has mentioned... page no 6